# MySQL Workbench Error 1005 cant create table

Tags: mysql

So I am **very new** to MySQL but I would like to think I that grasp a decent bit of it so far. I am struggling with the creation of the table `PROJECT`. I'm almost positive after my own research that it has something to do with my keys in the table. But I do not understand where the problem is or how to fix it.

The SQL queries below creates all tables for the project. I'm not sure of the problem because I only get the error code for the project for now. Any insight and advice on what causes this and how to rectify this in the code would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebrasi1db`.`employee` (
  `ssn` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `fname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `minit` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `bdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `superssn` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `dno` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ssn`),
  INDEX `superssn_idx` (`superssn` ASC),
  INDEX `dno_idx` (`dno` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `superssn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`superssn`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`employee` (`ssn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `dno`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dno`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`department` (`dnumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

 ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ebrasi1db`.`department`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebrasi1db`.`department` (
  `dnumber` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `mgrssn` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `mgrstartdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dnumber`),
  INDEX `mgrssn_idx` (`mgrssn` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `mgrssn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mgrssn`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`employee` (`ssn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ebrasi1db`.`dept_locations`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebrasi1db`.`dept_locations` (
  `dnumber` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `dlocation` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dnumber`, `dlocation`),
  CONSTRAINT `dnumber`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dnumber`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`department` (`dnumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ebrasi1db`.`project`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebrasi1db`.`project` (
  `pnumber` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `pname` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `plocation` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `dnum` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pnumber`),
  INDEX `dnum_idx` (`dnum` ASC),
  INDEX `plocation_idx` (`plocation` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `dnum`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dnum`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`department` (`dnumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `plocation`
    FOREIGN KEY (`plocation`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`dept_locations` (`dlocation`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ebrasi1db`.`works_on`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebrasi1db`.`works_on` (
  `essn` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `pno` INT NOT NULL,
  `hours` DECIMAL(5,2) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`essn`, `pno`),
  INDEX `pno_idx` (`pno` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `works_on_essn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`essn`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`employee` (`ssn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `pno`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pno`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`project` (`pnumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `ebrasi1db`.`dependent`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebrasi1db`.`dependent` (
  `essn` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `dependent_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `sex` VARCHAR(1) NULL,
  `bdate` DATE NULL,
  `relation` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`essn`, `dependent_name`),
  CONSTRAINT `dependent_essn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`essn`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`employee` (`ssn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Are you running this script in the order it is here?

Comment: Can you please share the error code that you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem lies essentially in the fact that you are trying to create a constraint to a non key column (because the referenced table has a double key).

In your table `project` you have:

```
CONSTRAINT `plocation`
FOREIGN KEY (`plocation`)
REFERENCES `dept_locations` (`dlocation`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

`dept_locations.dlocation` is not a key ALONE (primary key), therefore the reason you are not able to create that constraint.

You need to make the constraint for both keys from the referenced table like this:

```
CONSTRAINT `plocation`
FOREIGN KEY (`pnumber`, `plocation`)
REFERENCES `dept_locations` (`dnumber`, `dlocation`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
```

In this case you won't need the first constraint `dnum` as it is already referenced in `dept_locations` table.

Also note that you tables `department` and `employee` will not be created because one reference the other so you need to create the tables first without the constraints then apply the constraints like:

```
ALTER TABLE `employee` add 
CONSTRAINT `dno`
FOREIGN KEY (`dno`)
REFERENCES `department` (`dnumber`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```

Same for the `department` table and its constraint to `employee`

Comment: This was a very helpful answer. Really helped me understand how to adjust what i am doing. For someone so new it was killing me knowing what the problem was, but not a clue how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normally you get the Error 1005 when it unable to create the foreign keys. When you are creating a foreign key constraint the parent table should be available in the database.

In your case 'employee' table has a FK to 'department' table but you are trying to create the 'employee' table before creating the 'department' table. Also the 'department' table has a FK back to 'employee' table. Therefore you are not able to create the 'department' table first. To solve this you may create the 'department' table first without FK to 'employee' table. Then create the 'employee' table and then alter the 'department' table with FK.

Here is the modified code for first two tables and follow the same pattern for rest if you get the same error.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebrasi1db`.`department` (
`dnumber` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `dname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `mgrssn` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `mgrstartdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dnumber`),
  INDEX `mgrssn_idx` (`mgrssn` ASC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ebrasi1db`.`employee` (
  `ssn` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `fname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `minit` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `lname` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `bdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `address` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` VARCHAR(1) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `superssn` VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `dno` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ssn`),
  INDEX `superssn_idx` (`superssn` ASC),
  INDEX `dno_idx` (`dno` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `superssn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`superssn`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`employee` (`ssn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `dno`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dno`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`department` (`dnumber`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

 ENGINE = InnoDB;


alter table department  add
  CONSTRAINT `mgrssn`
    FOREIGN KEY (`mgrssn`)
    REFERENCES `ebrasi1db`.`employee` (`ssn`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
```